# How do I dynamically swap fragments of a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, replace, android-viewpager, swap

This is a long question but I have not yet find an answer on SO that works.  I am using a ViewPager to display three tabs (separate fragments).  My goal is that on the main tab (position 1), when I press a button, the button should disappear, and a **NEW** fragment containing a ListView should be populated where the button once was..

As it is now, the fragment that is being interacted with has a click listener on the button:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onButtonPressed();
        }
    });
```

which then calls

```
public void onButtonPressed() {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction();
    }
}
```

which leads to

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    public void onFragmentInteraction();
}
```

The Activity that hosts the tabs and everything implements ButtonFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener

```
/**
 * Handle fragment interaction and replacement
 */
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction() {
    XFragment fragment = new XFragment();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.button_layout_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

The container I am replacing is defined in XML as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/button_layout_container"
         android:padding="10dp">

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Which is being replaced by a layout defined like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:id="@+id/buddies_layout_container"
                       android:padding="10dp">

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list_view_buddies"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

As is, what is happening is that the list of buddies comes up but the button is still there and not clickable.  I press the hardware back button and the list disappears as it should, and the button is clickable.  **But how do I make the list fragment completely replace the button?**

Comment: simply what you can do is that, you can hide the button visibility and set it to GONE i.e. button.setVisibility(VIEW.GONE); The button is not hiding bcz you are using button_layout_container to replace fragment and in that layout button already have occupied it's space so unless you hide the button visibility it will not occupy all space in that layout.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I am replacing the layout containing the button with the layout containing the ListView.  So shouldn't the button disappear? The new FrameLayout (second XML) should replace the old FrameLayout (first XML) entirely.

Comment: NO BECAUSE YOU ARE USING FRAMELAYOUT SO IN FRAME LAYOUT IT OVERLAPS